# BitConverter vs Casting Differences

Tags: c#, performance, casting, byte

Given that:

```
int onlyLastByteContainsValue = 35;
```

Which of the following is faster and why?

```
byte valueInByte = BitConverter.GetBytes(onlyLastByteContainsValue)[3];
```

Or

```
byte valueInByte = (byte)onlyLastByteContainsValue;
```

***Follow-up question:*** Are there other differences between the two above?

Comment: Why don't you profile it and find out which is faster yourself? p.s., the cast _should_ be faster, unless the compiler is able to do some crazy magic with the first case.

Comment: I want to know why. Let me re-phrase the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naturally, the cast will be faster, from my profiling by up to x5 with optimizations off (and even moreso with optimizations on).

Of course there are different things going on:

- Your `BitConverter` statement allocates an array with a size of `sizeof(int)`, fills it with all the bytes of the int value, and then indexes the array to retrieve only one byte. It goes without saying that this is wasteful of resources.
- The cast checks that the specified value is within the range of `byte` (unless `unchecked` is specified), and casts the least significant byte of the value to a `byte`.